# how to change li:eq(0..i) to for loop?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question for for loop. I don't know how to make for loop properly. 
Below, event handler is different, but inside function is the same.
How to change each li:eq(0,1,2,....i) to for loop for making only one function?

```js
$(".section4 ul li:eq(0)").click(function() {
  $("#Apply").click(function() {
    var menuSelect = document.getElementById("menuSelect");
    //console.log(menuSelect);
    switch (menuSelect.value) {
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
        $("#tab1 .Apply_Check").append("<div class='User'>" + menuSelect.value + "</div>");
        break;
    }
  })
})

$(".section4 ul li:eq(1)").click(function() {
  $("#Apply").click(function() {
    var menuSelect = document.getElementById("menuSelect");
    //console.log(menuSelect);
    switch (menuSelect.value) {
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
        $("#tab2 .Apply_Check").append("<div class='User'>" + menuSelect.value + "</div>");
        break;
    }
  })
})

$(".section4 ul li:eq(2)").click(function() {
  $("#Apply").click(function() {
    var menuSelect = document.getElementById("menuSelect");
    //console.log(menuSelect);
    switch (menuSelect.value) {
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
        $("#tab3 .Apply_Check").append("<div class='User'>" + menuSelect.value + "</div>");
        break;
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="menuSelect">
  <option value="menu" selected="selected">selected</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<section class="section4">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#none"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#none"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#none"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#none"></a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab1">
    <div class="Apply_Check"></div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab2">
    <div class="Apply_Check"></div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab3">
    <div class="Apply_Check"></div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab4"></article>
</section>
```

Comment: Your HTML in the example above seems incomplete. Where is the `#Apply` button

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes to persist target element information

```
<ul>
    <li data-target="#tab1">
        <a href="#none">target 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Which can be accessed use `$.fn.data()` in the event handler.

```
$(".section4 ul li").click(function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target'); //retrieve target element
  $(target).find(".Apply_Check").html("<div class='User'>" + $("#menuSelect").val() + "</div>");
})
```

Note: You don't need to bind event handler in other event handler

```js
$(".section4 ul li").click(function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target')
  $(target).find(".Apply_Check").html("<div class='User'>" + $("#menuSelect").val() + "</div>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="menuSelect">
  <option value="menu" selected="selected">selected</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<section class="section4">
  <ul>
    <li data-target="#tab1">
      <a href="#none">target 1</a>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#tab2">
      <a href="#none">target 2</a>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#tab3">
      <a href="#none">target 3</a>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#tab4">
      <a href="#none">target 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab1">
    <div class="Apply_Check">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab2">
    <div class="Apply_Check">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab3">
    <div class="Apply_Check">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab4">
    <div class="Apply_Check">
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

---

Snippet, If you need to show text on the click of apply button

```js
$(".section4 ul li").click(function() {
  //Set the target
  $('#Apply').data('target', $(this).data('target'));
})

$('#Apply').on('click', function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $(target).find(".Apply_Check").html("<div class='User'>" + $("#menuSelect").val() + "</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="Apply">Apply</button>
<select id="menuSelect">
  <option value="menu" selected="selected">selected</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>



<section class="section4">
  <ul>
    <li data-target="#tab1">
      <a href="#none">target 1</a>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#tab2">
      <a href="#none">target 2</a>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#tab3">
      <a href="#none">target 3</a>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#tab4">
      <a href="#none">target 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab1">
    <div class="Apply_Check">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab2">
    <div class="Apply_Check">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab3">
    <div class="Apply_Check">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab4">
    <div class="Apply_Check">
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely unsure about what you are tryingto achieve - but here is a function that will append the selected value of the select list to the div. You can then apply the same logic to your situation. Would also suggest a cleaner HTML structure.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menuSelect").change(function() {
    var menuSelect = $(this).val();
    $("#tab1 .Apply_Check").append("<div class='User'>" + menuSelect + "</div>");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="menuSelect">
  <option value="menu" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<hr/>

<section class="section4">
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab1">
    <div class="Apply_Check">

    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab2">
    <div class="Apply_Check">

    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab3">
    <div class="Apply_Check">

    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab4">

  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the `index` and get the desired element by `$('.PaNel:eq(' + indexVal + ') .Apply_Check')`

```js
var selectVal = $('#menuSelect').val(),
  indexVal;
$('.section4 a').on('click', function() {
  indexVal = $(this).parent().index();
  setContent();
})

$('#menuSelect').on('change', function() {
  selectVal = $(this).val();
  setContent();
})

var setContent = function() {
  if (typeof indexVal !== undefined) {
    $('.Apply_Check').html('');
    $('.PaNel:eq(' + indexVal + ') .Apply_Check').append("<div class='User'>" + selectVal + "</div>");
  }
}
```

```css
.PaNel {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="menuSelect">
  <option value="menu" selected="selected">selected</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<section class="section4">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#none">Show Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#none">Show Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#none">Show Tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#none">Show Tab 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <article class="PaNel" id="tab1">T1
    <div class="Apply_Check"></div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab2">T2
    <div class="Apply_Check"></div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab3">T3
    <div class="Apply_Check"></div>
  </article>
  <article class="PaNel" id="tab4">T4
    <div class="Apply_Check"></div>
  </article>
</section>
```